# Autocomplete using key press as well as enter key trigger

Tags: jquery

I have to do autocomplete search by keypress and also after pressing enter key.After keypress it is working fine but it is not working after pressing enter key. For Keypress i used

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('.input-search-text').on('focus', function(){
       var $this = $(this),
         searchType = $("#network").find('.dd-selected-value').val().toLowerCase(),
         searchURL = $(".form-search-users").attr('action');

   $this.autocomplete({
       //Remaining stuff.
   })
})
```

Which is working fine. But for enter key i used

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.input-search-text').keypress(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       if(e.which == 13) {
            getSearch($this);
       }
   });
});

function getSearch(object) {
    var $this = object,
        searchType = $("#network").find('.dd-selected-value').val().toLowerCase(),
        searchURL = $(".form-search-users").attr('action');

    $this.autocomplete({
        // Remaining stuff ...
    }); 
}
```

My code is working fine before $this.autocomplete({ }). But by some reason $this is not working and If i use direct id like

```
$('#input).autocomplete({
        // Remaining stuff ...
});
```

then it work fine. Please tell me from where i need change to make this working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use autocomplete widget's method `search` in your `getSearch` function:

```
function getSearch(object) {
    var $this = object,
        searchType = $("#network").find('.dd-selected-value').val().toLowerCase(),
        searchURL = $(".form-search-users").attr('action');

    $this.autocomplete({
        // Remaining stuff ...
    })
    .autocomplete('search', $this.val()); 
}
```

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search